# Relacionamento many-to-many Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-eloquent, laravel-5.3

Boa tarde.
Estou desenvolvendo um sistema em Laravel 5.3 com as seguintes tabelas:
[image: tabelas]

A partir do id de comissão, preciso trazer todos os dados relacionados em uma view onde listará numa tabela quais os parlamentares que fazem parte (um por linha), qual seu cargo na comissão, qual o período de atuação etc.

Comment: Qual os nomes dos models? Para adequar o mais possivel ao que tens

Comment: Usei nos models os mesmos nomes das tabelas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No model Comissao.php deves fazer a tua relação :

```
...
public function parlamentares() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Parlamentar', 'composicao_comissao', 'cod_comissao', 'cod_parlamentar')->withPivot('dat_designacao', 'cod_periodo_comp', 'ind_titular', 'outras colunas da tabela pivot que queiras aceder via esta relacao');
}
...
```

Model Parlamentar.php (opcional, visto que não mencionas precisar desta relação na pergunta):

```
...
public function comissoes() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Comissao', 'composicao_comissao',  'cod_parlamentar', 'cod_comissao')->withPivot('dat_designacao', 'cod_periodo_comp', 'ind_titular', 'outras colunas da tabela pivot que queiras aceder via esta relacao');
}
...
```

**EX:**

```
$comissao_1 = App\Comissao::find(1);
```

Envias os dados `$comissao_1` para a view, e lá podes fazer, ex (parto do princípio que estás a usar *template blade*):

```
@foreach($comissao_1->parlamentares as $par)
    {{$par->nome_completo}} -> {{$par->pivot->cod_periodo_comp}}<br>
@endforeach
```

Nota `pivot`, são as informações (colunas) a que queres aceder na tabela pivot (`composicao_comissao`), `cod_periodo_comp` neste caso. É preciso declara-las na relação dentro dos models, tal como o exemplo acima.

[DOCS](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Comment: Usando esta lógica, como poderia recuperar o nome do parlamentar que está na tabela parlamentar e o cargo que ele ocupa?

Comment: @AmaroCorrea, o nome coloquei no exemplo. O cargo pensando por alto poderia ser: `App\Cargo::find($par->pivot->cod_cargo)->des_cargo`, mas talvez consigas fazer uma relação para isto.