# Tabela de Relacionamentos MySql

Tags: php, tabela-html, modelo-relacional

Eu tenho uma view chamada 'clientes.blade' onde o administrador irá escolher quais clientes um determinado desenvolvedor pode ver, porém, não sei como salvar essas alterações no banco de dados.

**Model**

```
public function Clientes ()
{
    return $this->hasMany("Clients"); //conectando as tabelas 'users' e 'clients' do banco de dados
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function updateClient()
    {
        var_dump(Input::get("clientes"));
        $user = \App\User::find(Input::get("id"));
    }
```

**Clientes.blade**

```
<form method="POST" action="/user/update/client">

    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$id}}" />

    <h1>BEM VINDO ADMINISTRADOR!</h1>

    <div><input type="button" value="Início" id="inicio" name="Início" onclick="window.location.href='/inicioadm';"></div> <br>

     @foreach ($clients as $client)

    <table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
    <th width="30%"><p>Nome: {{$client->Nome}} <input name="clientes[]" type="checkbox" value="{{$client->ID}}"> </p></th>       
    </tr>
    </table>

    @endforeach

    <br><div><input type="submit" value="Salvar" id="salvar" name="Salvar" onclick="window.location.href='/desenvolvedores"/div>


</form>
```

Comment: Acho que tens de explicar mais Vitória, o que tens na base de dados para rastrear isso? O que vai diferenciar na base de dados os clientes um determinado desenvolvedor pode ver dos outros?

Comment: Tenho uma tabela de relacionamentos com id, id_user e id_client.

Comment: Eu quero que ao clicar em 'Selecionar Clientes', o Administrador poderá escolher quais clientes o Desenvolvedor poderá ver e salvar isso na tabela.

Comment: tens no Model dos desencolvedores a relaçao hasmany con os clientes certo?

Comment: Nao... Eu coloquei 'belongToMany'... está errado???

Comment: public function clients ()
    {
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\client');  
    }

Comment: Tentei fazer esse código, porém, dá erro:
public function clientes($id)
    {
        $clients = \App\client::all();
        $user = \App\User::find($id);
        $UC = \App\relationModel::where('user_id', $user->id)->get();
        
        $userClients = array();
        
        foreach($UC as $item)
        {
            $userClients[] = $item->client_id;
        }
        
        return View('/clientes')->with(array('clients' => $clients, 'user' => $user, 'userClients' => $userClients));
    }

Comment: Ha ok percebi, porque um cliente pode ser editado por um ou mais desenvokvedores, e um desenvolvedor pode editar um ou mais clientes, certo?

Comment: Se estiver tudo certo com a relação podes usar attach, https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships... estás a usar Laravel certo?

Comment: Isso... isso mesmo! Dai eu tenho uma view que possui 4 checkbox, dai ao 'checar' cada cliente, será o que o desenvolvedor poderá 'ver/editar'.

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'projeto.relation_models' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `relation_models` where `user_id` = 1)

Comment: não sei precisava de mais dados /: . Tens algum sitio com o codigo? Este link pode ajudar, https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: Consegui... Valeu cara!

Comment: boa Vitória (: , só dei um empurrãozinho. Isto também pode ajudar http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/193258/5749