# Relação entre 3 tabelas com pivot

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Tenho a seguinte estrutura que tenho que seguir.

Filmes
Pessoas 
TiposDePessoas ( Ator, Cinegrafista, Diretor)

Aonde Cada Pessoa HasMany TiposDePessoas
E Cada Filme HasMany Pessoa

Ou seja, Cada filme vai ter os campos Diretor, Cinegrafista, etc
Aonde será selecionado as Pessoas que são deste tipo.

A forma como eu estou fazendo não está dando o resultado esperado.

A relação de tabelas está assim

Pessoas
https://gist.github.com/lucassmacedo/e6528571a356eeaa358dc07c8e97d19c

Tabelas e Relações
https://gist.github.com/lucassmacedo/928b4c2a1ef038e453cb8fc02edd2ee0

a idéia que é no admin, possa ser cadastrados quantas pessoas for necessário dentro de cada  genero, ator, diretor, etc

quando eu insiro os dados na tabela pivot

ele fica sobrescrevendo os valores

se a pessoa já foi cadastrada em ateriormente em outra type

ela sobrescreve

Comment: Acho que isto te pode ajudar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/193211/relacionamento-many-to-many-laravel-5/193258#193258

Comment: Eu vendo assim parece problema das estruturas feitas e logica empregada